# Android HttpPost doesn't work and it crashes

Tags: android, http-post

I simply have:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Creating HTTP Post
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
        "http://www.google.com/");

// Making HTTP Request
try {
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    // writing response to log
    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I run the app, it crashes and does not work.

this my log:

```
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myapppp/com.app.myapppp.Main}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at com.app.myapppp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:133)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
02-05 14:33:42.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25026):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception this is the solution, please search well before posting.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your trying to do network related operations in your main activity.
Which is not allowed rather is a bad way to do network related task.
To do all such a task there are other ways such as you can do that by AsyncTask class.

Which allows you to do all this big task on the background of your application.
So that your main thread does not get to busy which apparently causes your application crash.

documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

simple asyncTask example http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

Answer (score 0):

Need to perform network operation in separate thread.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new NetworkOperation().execute();
    }
```

Asynctask exapmle

```
private class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Creating HTTP Post
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.google.com/");

// Making HTTP Request
            try {
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```